# in Lucene what is the purpose of SetDefaultFieldSortScoring?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

When sorting, the sort rule applies to all returned documents. So scores are not taken into account. So when would one use SetDefaultFieldSortScoring to turn scoring on while sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to force lucene to compute scores of the results, even though they won't be sorted by the score. [api](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) This way you can display the score. Or perhaps highlight the more relevant results